# Order topology in $\omega^\alpha + 1$ and dynamical systems

Tags: general-topology, ordinals, order-topology

Let $f \colon \omega^\alpha + 1 \to \omega^\alpha + 1$, where $\alpha \geq 1$ a continous funciton such that, exists $w \in \omega^\alpha + 1$ with $\mathcal{O}_f(w)$ dense in $\omega^\alpha + 1$.

The set $\mathcal{O}_f(w)$ is the orbit of $w$, ie, $\mathcal{O}_f(w) = \{ w, f(w), f^2(w), \dots \}$.

With this conditions, we have that: If $y \in \omega^\alpha + 1$ is limit point and $f(y)$ is isolated point, then:

- the set $\{ z \in \omega^\alpha + 1 \colon f(z) = f(y) \}$ is open and infinite.
- There are $k < l$ such that $f(f^k(w)) = f(f^l(w)) = f(y)$.

I am not entirely clear why the above is true, I would appreciate a suggestion regarding the two previous statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any successor ordinal $\beta + 1$, the set $\{z \in  \omega^\alpha + 1 : f(z) = \beta + 1\}$ is open. Notice it is just $f^{-1}[(\beta,\beta+2)]$, so it is open by continuity of $f$.

Then $f^{-1}[\{f(y)\}]$ is open ($f(y)$ is a successor ordinal) and contains $y$, so for some $z < y$ we see $(z,y+1) \subseteq f^{-1}[\{f(y)\}]$. Since $y$ is a limit ordinal, $(z,y+1)$ is infinite. In fact, $(z,y+1)$ contains infinitely many (we only need 2 of them) isolated points. By the density of the orbit of $w$, there exists $k < l$ such that $f^k(w)$ and $f^l(w)$ are distinct elements of $f^{-1}[\{f(y)\}]$, in which case $f(f^k(w)) = f(f^l(w)) = f(y)$.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much. I have another question, are the limit points of $\omega^\alpha + 1$ are isolated, between them? Thanks.

Comment: $x$ is a limit pont means every open neighborhood of $x$ contains a point other than $x$. $x$ is an isolated point means there is an open neighborhood of $x$ which contains only $x$. So here limit points are exactly the limit ordinals and isolated points are the successor ordinals. Does that answer what you're asking?

Comment: no exactly, my question is, that limit points $x$ with CB(x) = 1 (where CB(x) is the cantor bedinxson rank, ie) are isolated, but this is true by definition of Cantor Bendixson Rank

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Yes, if $CB(x) = 1$ then $x$ is isolated in the first derivative $X^{(1)}$ a.k.a. isolated in the set of all limit points of $X$. In general, if $CB(x) = \alpha$ then $x$ is isolated in $X^{(\alpha)}$.